# Random multivariate normal distribution

Tags: java, random, distribution

I've run into a problem where I have to be able to generate a set of randomly chosen numbers of a multivariate normal distribution with mean 0 and a given 3*3 variance-covariance matrix in Java.

Is there an easy way as to do this?

Comment: In case you are looking for a library, probably apache commons math has something for cases like this. (Though in that case probably http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ a better site to ask.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Use a library implementation, as suggested by Dima.

Or, if you really feel a burning need to do this yourself:

2) Assuming you want to generate normals with a mean vector M and variance/covariance matrix V, perform [Cholesky Decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) on V to come up with lower triangular matrix L such that V=LL<sup>t</sup> (where the superscript t indicates transpose).  Generate a vector Z of three independent standard normals (using `Random.nextGaussian()` to get the individual elements). Then `LZ + M` will have the desired multivariate normal distribution.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/MultivariateNormalDistribution.html) has what you are looking for:

```
MultivariateNormalDistribution mnd = new MultivariateNormalDistribution(means, covariances);
double vals[] = mnd.sample();
```