# Create N-Dimensional normal distribution from single ones (in python)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, distribution, normal-distribution, gauss

Is there a general solution for this? You have to multiply them, but it is hard to implement.

For the 2 Dimensional case you can use the [*outer product*](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) of the two vector representing single normal distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution and tested in 2d case. It seems good, but I'll test it on more cases:

```
def normal_nd(*priors):
    # Trivial case
    if len(priors) == 1:
        return priors

    # General case
    shape = []
    for item in priors:
        shape.append(len(item))
    n = np.ones(shape)

    for idx, _ in np.ndenumerate(n):
        for ax, element in enumerate(idx):
            n[idx] *= priors[ax][element]

    return n
```

[image: 2d case plot]

Edit:
I tested it in general cases too, it seems it is a correct solution! :)

Answer (score 3):

The general solution involves [Cholesky decomposition of the variance/covariance matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823738/random-multivariate-normal-distribution/27824159#27824159).  Cholesky decomposition is available in Python via [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.cholesky.html).